# The adjacent_difference algorithm, and back_inserter vector<vector<int>>

Tags: c++, algorithm

I apply the `adjacent_difference` algorithm to the vector to work with elements in pairs, then `adjacent_difference` calls `diff` function which processes elements and gives the vector of various elements, which I want to insert in `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` but `back_inserter` does not work. If you work simply with `std::vector<int>` and return only int from `diff` function, then `back_inserter` succeeds. Help solve the problem. It does not compile(((

```
std::vector<int> dif(int prev, int val)
{
    std::vector<int> arr;
    if(prev < val)
        for(int i = prev; i < val; i++)
            arr.push_back(i);
    else
        for(int i = prev; i > val; i--)
            arr.push_back(i);
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> arr {1, 2, 6, 8, 10};
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> n;
    std::adjacent_difference(arr.begin(), arr.end(), std::back_inserter(n), dif);
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

`/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_numeric.h|374|error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<std::vector<int> > >’ and ‘_ValueType {aka int}’)|`

Comment: My code in std::adjacent_difference does not work for me. Namely std:: back_inserter(n)

Comment: Define "does not work". Does it not compile? Does it crash? Does it give an incorrect result?

Comment: it does not compile(((

Comment: Then post the compilation error, since it probably says what's wrong.

Comment: Added error output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the description of the algorithm

> First, **creates an accumulator acc whose type is InputIt's value
>   type**, initializes it with *first, and assigns the result to
>   *d_first. Then, for every iterator i in [first + 1, last) in order, creates an object val whose type is InputIt's value type, initializes
>   it with *i, computes val - acc (overload (1)) or op(val, acc)
>   (overload (3)), assigns the result to *(d_first + (i - first)), and
>   move assigns from val to acc.

So the accumulator for you call of the algorithm has the type `int` while you are trying to assign an object of the type `std::vector<int>` to it.